# How one derives this formula?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

Recently I have seen the following formula for motion of rigid body with a fixed point:
$$\dfrac{dT}{dt}=\int\limits_{0}^{t}M_{O}(\tau)d\tau$$ and I have no clue how this formula is derived. Could you help?

$T$ *is a kinetic energy*, $M_{O}$ *is a torque about point* $O$.

Comment: Does $t$ ($\tau$) represent time?

Comment: yes, it does:::

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you get the formula:

$$\dfrac{dT}{dt}=\int\limits_{0}^{t}M_{O}(\tau)d\tau$$

from.

But there cannot be *kinetic energy* **without motion**. The formula doesn't imply motion because a torque $M_{O}(\tau)$ can be applied indefinitely without motion occurring for all of time: no motion still means no kinetic energy.

---

Somewhat similar looking would be:

$$\mathrm{d}W=M_O\mathrm{d}\theta$$
where $W$ is work and $\theta$ the angle of rotation (the formula really only works in specific conditions but let that slide for now)

Then with the *work-energy theorem*:

$$\mathrm{d}T=\mathrm{d}W=M_O\mathrm{d}\theta$$
Divide both sides with $\mathrm{d}t$:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}T}{\mathrm{d}t}=M_O\omega$$

Comment: But is there any conditions, which make this formula true?

Comment: Not without modification, absolutely not. I'm going to edit the answer.